# Ensuring instances of the class have unique attributes' values

Tags: python, class, unique

Say i have a class myclass

```
class myclass:
    def __init__(self,x,y,count):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.count = count

    def add(self,count):
        self.count += count
```

How do I prevent two instances of myclass of having the same `x` and `y`? When this happens, `add()` should be called instead of `__init__()`, which updates the count of an existing `myclass()` object instead of creating a new one.

Comment: This probably isn’t something this class should worry about, but another container class that contains a lot of instances of this one.

Comment: @deceze but how?

Comment: Why are you doing this with a class? It seems like it should just be a dictionary that uses the tuple `(x, y)` as the keys.

Comment: @Barmar I have more functions in this class that are not related to init or add. I just need a way of making sure there are no instances with the same x and y.

Comment: agreed with Barmar, even if you want to stick with classes for the instances, these classes should perhaps be kept in a dict container, with `(x, y)` as the keys. That way, before initializing a new instance, you can check if an instance with those x y values already exists.

Comment: But what if there is a function that depends on x and y? How can I get those values if they are stored in an outside dict?

Comment: @user13068713 store them in the class as usual as well. you don't have to store the x y *only* in the keys. The keys are there to make sure there's a unique object with that value, but your objects dont have to change to accomodate it

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `myclass()` to create new objects. Define another function that keeps a dictionary of all the objects, and returns a new one if there isn't one already.

```
all_myclass = {}
def get_myclass(x, y, count):
    if (x, y) not in all_myclass:
        all_myclass[(x, y)] = myclass(x, y, count)
    return all_myclass[(x, y)]
```

All other code should use `get_myclass()` instead of `myclass()`.

Note: this assumes that you never change `x` or `y` once you create the object.

Comment: So I need to write a seperate `minus()` function if I have to change x and y?

Comment: If it's more complex, you should probably define a new class that implements the container. All the methods in that class should take `x, y` arguments. They look up the element in the dictionary, and then call the corresponding method on the object. Then if you need to change x and y, you do it through that class, so it can update the dictionary.